# MacMath-like Program (for Linux)?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, math-software

I saw John Hubbard (of Cornell University) give a lecture on differential equations/dynamical systems using a [MacMath](https://smile.amazon.com/MacMath-9-2-Dynamical-Software-MacintoshTM/dp/0387941355) program he evidently wrote. Does anyone know of a similar software package for Linux? I would like to use it to illustrate chaos and resonance to my Diff Eqs classes.

Comment: Does this program plot flow lines in phase space?  I think there are websites that do that with JavaScript.

Comment: Someone had posited XPP http://www.math.pitt.edu/~bard/xpp/xpp.html as a software package to do what I want, and that's pretty much exactly for what I was looking. I already got it to animate a pendulum with both chaotic and resonant driving terms, and hope to get it to animate a mass-spring-dashpot system on a frictionless surface with both chaotic and resonant driving terms soon.